# Android remove focus from all Views

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

This is a fairly simple question but I can't believe all answers I found were not working.

I have a layout with two `EditText` and the bottom of the window is just some remaining blank space. I'd like each `EditText` to loose focus when the user is clicking in the blank part of the window. So my guess is that I have to put something in the `OnTouchListener` of the root `View`:

```
rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // Put something here
    }
});
```

I have tried several things:

- Requesting focus from the layout `View` as suggested somewhere was in fact giving focus to one of the `EditText`s.
- I also tried setting `setFocusable` for both `EditText`s to `false` but I was unable to put them back to `true` afterwards.
- I also tried the simple `rootView.clearFocus()`, but it was also giving back the focus to one `EditText`.

EDIT: My `EditText` boxes are multilines so I can't use a 'Done' keyboard button since I need the return one to be present.

Comment: Have you tried `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` on your root view? Please post your layout files as well.

Comment: `rootView` is your editText? cause u need to call [`clearFocus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearFocus%28%29) on your editText.

Comment: btw, this `clearFocus()` doesn't work if editText is your **only** view, `clearFocus()` returns focus to first focusable view.

Answer (score 19):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/ll_root_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

LinearLayout llRootView = findViewBindId(R.id.ll_root_view);
llRootView.clearFocus();
```

I use this when already finished update profile info and remove all focus from EditText in my layout

====> Update: In parent layout content my EditText add line:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: Honestly it is the best answer I've found on whole stack overflow. Great thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin:

```
view?.clearFocus()
```

In Java:

```
getView().clearFocus();
```